# Drop Down menu Hidden by a Div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Below are the CSS classes in my web application

```
#header {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    background:url(Images/header.png);
    background-size:100% 86%;
    width:100%;
    height:16%;
    z-index:200;
}
#centre {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:16%;
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
        z-index:101;

}
#smoothmenu1 {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    width:50%;
    bottom:0px;
    height:26px;
    z-index:180;
}
```

**smoothmenu1** `div` is nested in header `div` , smooth menu div contains a drop down menubar , due to some reasons , on drop down , the menu items seem to be hiding behind center div .I'm trying to add menubar in smoothmenu1 div as shown here . http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm

Following is the HTML section

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/ddsmoothmenu.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/ddsmoothmenu.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
ddsmoothmenu.init({
    mainmenuid: "smoothmenu1", //menu DIV id
    orientation: 'h', //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
    classname: 'ddsmoothmenu', //class added to menu's outer DIV
    //customtheme: ["#1c5a80", "#18374a"],
    contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
})
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#centre').load("initCentre.html"); 
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#main {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
#header {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    background:url(Images/header.png);
    background-size:100% 88%;
    width:100%;
    height:14%;
    z-index:250;
}
#centre {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:16%;
    width:100%;
    height:82%;
        z-index:300;

}
#smoothmenu1 {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    width:50%;
    bottom:0px;
    height:26px;
    z-index:220;
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:4%;
    z-index:2;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="header">
<div id="smoothmenu1" class="ddsmoothmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">menu3</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Sub Item 1.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Sub Item 1.2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Sub Item 1.3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Sub Item 1.4</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Sub Item 1.2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Sub Item 1.3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Sub Item 1.4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">menu2</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Sub Item 1.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Sub Item 1.2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Sub Item 1.3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Sub Item 1.4</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Sub Item 1.2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Sub Item 1.3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Sub Item 1.4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">menu1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/">menu3</a></li>
</ul>
<br style="clear: left" />
</div>
</div>
<div id="centre"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Generally overlapping happens because of Z-index. Try to adjust z-index for smoothmenu.

Comment: Please provide your html if anything

Comment: i've added HTML portion of my code

Comment: Oh my god, why is everything absolute!? (I'm hoping there's a genuine reason)

Comment: here's the jsfiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/f52pF/

Answer (score 1):

Your `#centre` element has a higher `z-index` - try switching them.

Slightly off-topic: try laying out your document without `absolute` elements where possible.

Comment: @c.pramod As suggested above, can you sort out a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Your #center has a z-index of 300, but #header and #smoothmenu are 250 and 220 respectively.  300 is higher, making it appear over the top of the other two divs.   Set #center divs z-index to be less than headers if you don't want it to cover #header and it's children.

Comment: Works for me in the code you pasted above.  I set z-index:240 for #center and the menu appeared above the center div.   What browsers are you testing it in?